# change the name into majuscule

Tags: python, arcpy

I have this python script and i need to fill new field (TOPONYME_Maj) by attributes from TOPONEME but they are in  minuscule and i need to change them to majuscule. I have no idea how it should look like.thanks for help

```
inFC  = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) 

arcpy.AddField_management (inFC, u"TOPONYME_Maj", "STRING")

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(inFC,["TOPONYME",u"TOPONYME_Maj"]) as rows:
    for row in rows:
        row[1] = row[0]
        rows.updateRow(row)
        row[1] = row[1].upper()
        rows.updateRow(row[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues with your script:

1. You only need to update the row once per iteration.
2. Update the row variable rather than the row index.

I also added some logic to handle `None` type data in the attributes, which would otherwise yield an error if encountered.

---

```
inFC  = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0) 

arcpy.AddField_management (inFC, u"TOPONYME_Maj", "STRING")

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(inFC,["TOPONYME",u"TOPONYME_Maj"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] != None:
            row[1] = row[0].upper()
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```